# How to get Day of Week

Tags: powershell, dayofweek

I know you can use dayofweek function to get day of week. For instance

```
(Get-Date).DayOfWeek works
```

But I am looking to get the day of a specific date so i have

```
$lastquarter="select convert (char,(SELECT DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0))), 23) as lastquarter"
```

This print out

> 2022-12-31

When I do

```
$DayofWeek=$lastquarter_day.DayOfWeek
```

I get nothing

```
$DayofWeek=$lastquarter_day.DayOfWeek
```

I get nothing

Comment: That looks like a SQL query, you'll need to execute it first

Comment: I would say `(Get-Date $lastquarter).DayOfWekk` assuming you have actually ran the query as Paolo stated in his comment

Comment: Can you show how you're initialising ```$lastquarter_day```?

Comment: If `$lastquarter` is a **string** resulting from your sql query, then you need to convert that to a DateTime object first using `([datetime]::ParseExact($lastquarter, 'yyyy-MM-dd', $null)).DayOfWeek`

Comment: I believe `yyyy-MM-dd` format is locale-independent, it should be enough to directly cast it as a datetime: `([datetime]$lastquarter).DayOfWeek` for me outputs `Saturday` (given `$lastquarter = '2022-12-31'` as a test)